# Transformer in apache collection15

Tags: java

What is the use of the Transformer function in the apache commons collection ?

How do I use it in programs and at what times?

Answer (score 4):

`Transformers` are **[function objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object)** (also referred abusively as ["software" functors](http://chaoticjava.com/posts/functors-in-java-and-beyond/), even though functor are a [mathematical notion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Functor.html) from the Category Theory).
They represent a function encapsulated in an object.

In most cases, the function’s parameters can be set and the result retrieved using the common accessors pattern, such as `setParameter1(Object value)` or `getResult()`.

The fact that these functions are encapsulated by real objects is also the reason for its greatest benefit: the **use of many design patterns including structural ones** such as the Decorator pattern and behavioral ones such as the Visitor pattern.

So you use `Transformers` to apply a pattern on Collections, but also on [other objects](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/TransformerExample.htm).

Here is an example of a [creational pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern) [used through a Transformer](http://apachecommonstipsandtricks.blogspot.com/2009/01/transformer-invoker-for-collection-of.html).

Comment: This use of "functor" is incorrect, although widely held. A functor is actually a type-level transformation. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Functor.html

Comment: @Apocalisp: Agreed. I have corrected the answer to reflect the distinction between functor and "function object"